# Detener animacion de Morphext cuando termine las frases

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

estoy intentando algunas animaciones con `Morphext` y la verdad que me ha gustado mucho, por ahora deseo que se detenga la publicación al llegar a la ultima palabra o frase que este dentro del `id="js-rotating"` pero no he podido.....

traduje la documentación y no me fue muy bien tampoco... quien pueda ayudarme le agradecería.

```js
$("#js-rotating").Morphext({
    // The [in] animation type. Refer to Animate.css for a list of available animations.
    animation: "bounceIn",
    // An array of phrases to rotate are created based on this separator. Change it if you wish to separate the phrases differently (e.g. So Simple | Very Doge | Much Wow | Such Cool).
    separator: ",",
    // The delay between the changing of each phrase in milliseconds.
    speed: 2000,
    complete: function () {
        // Called after the entrance animation is executed.
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Morphext/2.4.4/morphext.min.js"></script>

<span id="js-rotating">Primero, Segundo, Para Aqui</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes evaluar el índice de la cantidad de palabras y detener el flujo cuando llegue al límite:

```js
$("#js-rotating").Morphext({
    // The [in] animation type. Refer to Animate.css for a list of available animations.
    animation: "bounceIn",
    // An array of phrases to rotate are created based on this separator. Change it if you wish to separate the phrases differently (e.g. So Simple | Very Doge | Much Wow | Such Cool).
    separator: ",",
    // The delay between the changing of each phrase in milliseconds.
    speed: 2000,
    complete: function () {
        // Called after the entrance animation is executed.
        if (this.index === 2) {
          this.stop(true);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Morphext/2.4.4/morphext.min.js"></script>

<span id="js-rotating">Primero, Segundo, Para Aqui</span>
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: muy amable de tu parte, agradecida. <3